# Nodejs line-by-line close calling next line?

Tags: node.js, readfile, line-by-line

I'm using the plugin [line-by-line](https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-by-line) to read a very large file. There's a case where I want just the first line, so I'd close the connection immediately in that case.

However, I was noticing that it would try to process the next line regardless. I dumbed it down as far as I could, and wrote this:

```
lr.on("line", function (line) {
  lr.pause();
  console.log("\rLine");
  lr.close();
}
```

My console shows:

`Line`

`Line`

Without the `lr.close()`, it only logs `Line` once.

What am I missing?

Comment: try `lr.end();` It print last line because it already read it as `lineFragment`.

Comment: @vp_arth That should be an answer, works as expected. Didn't see that in the doc...

Comment: Source is the best documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to [Source](https://github.com/Osterjour/line-by-line/blob/master/line-by-line.js)

It print last `lineFragment` for you.
If you don't need it - call `lr.end();`.

---